# Python + Sqlite 3 query with multiple conditions

Tags: python, sqlite

I want to query a table `paths` with 5 columns (`user`, `trial` , `t`, `x`, `y`) to get user, `trial` and `t` where first condition: `x*x+y*y<100` and second condition: `t` has the max value.

I solved only the half of the problem, implemented the first condition:

```
query = '''
    SELECT user, trial , t, 
    FROM paths
    WHERE x*x+y*y<100
    '''
```

Got this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8hXc.png)

I must add the second condition such as only the `user + trial` with max value for `t` should be selected. Example: `row 1226 5 2.348045`

Please help me to find a solution.
Thank you!

Comment: Pick one from [`[python] [sqlite3] multiple WHERE`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=isanswered%3Ayes+is%3Aquestion+%5Bpython%5D+%5Bsqlite3%5D+multiple+WHERE)

Comment: I'm not quite sure what "`t` has the max value" means. Could you explain? Is `t` greater than `x` and `y`, greater than `user` or `trial`?

Comment: The sqlite website has a lot of documentation, much of which seems to be geared to those who already know SQL. So I would suggest you take a look at [www.sqlitetutorial.net](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/). That site gives lots of examples of the different features of the SQL dialect as understood by sqlite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For SQLite3 specifically (it won't work with any SQL), you can simply change `t` to `max(t) t` in your `SELECT` statement. (Also, remove the dangling comma after `t,`).

If you need max for each user, add `GROUP BY user` at the end.